# Agora Token Error: could not handle the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, dart, agora.io

i am trying to create my generate a token from Agora but i keep getting this result

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

after i test the HTTP. I was unable to figure out there the error is coming from
Here is my code

```
const {RtcTokenBuilder, RctRole}= require("agora-access-token");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const moment = require("moment");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const app = express();
// create your port
// const PORT = 8089;
const appId = "83....c";
const appCertificate = "8d....5";
app.use(cors({origin: true}));

const nocache = (res, resp, next) => {
  resp.header("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache, nostore, must-revalidate");
  resp.header("Expires", "-1");
  resp.header("Pragma", "no-cache");
};

const generateAccessToken = (req, resp) => {
  // set header
  resp.header("Acess-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  // channel name
  const channelName = req.query.channelName;
  if (!channelName) {
    return req.status(500).json({"error": "channel Name is required"});
  }
  // get uid
  let uid = req.query.uid;
  if (!uid || uid == "") {
    uid = 0;
  }
  // get the role
  let role = RctRole.SUBSCRIBER;
  if (req.query.role == "publisher") {
    role = RctRole.PUBLISHER;
  }
  // get expiring time
  let expireTime = req.query.expireTime;
  if (!expireTime || expireTime == "") {
    expireTime = 3600;
  } else {
    expireTime = parseInt(expireTime, 10);
  }
  // calculate Priviledge expre time
  const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const privilegeExpiereTime = currentTime + expireTime;
  // build the token
  const token = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(appId, appCertificate, channelName, uid, role, privilegeExpiereTime);
  return req.json({"token": token});
};
app.get("/access_token", nocache, generateAccessToken);
exports.tokenAgora = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Looks like the actual error message comes from Firebase. Posting the log output from `firebase functions:log` might be helpful, if you can access it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs

Comment: where? i have put try catch but not show anything just showing time out

Comment: Like I said, I think the exception is occurring in Firebase, not in the node runtime, so a try-catch won't catch it. I don't use Firebase, all I know is that googling the error only brings up Firebase questions on SO. Read the link I posted and set up logging or ctrl+f to the section on the CLI tool, that might help you.